# Macro to delete rows from columns that have less that 4 characters

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to try and delete entire rows when it has less than 4 characters in the specific "NAME" column. (ie a column with the header in row 1 being NAME) The database currently has around 10,000 rows. I know the code right now is close, but I am getting a VB error when trying to run it. I think I might be searching for the specific column by name wrong.

```
Sub Macro2()

' Macro to delete rows if there are less than 4 in the NAME column

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LR = Range("NAME" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Range("NAME" & i).Value) < 4 Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Edit: I am getting the VBA error in the following line:

```
LR = Range("NAME" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: I can't get what is this NAME thing because you probably won't have so many named range? Two options: your code is wrong when checking a range (better use `.Cells(i,j)` or you'd better check if your named range exists

Comment: Is the "NAME" cell in a specific column(s)? Is it always the same? I would reference that value directly then, as @JMax describes, with `.Cells(i, j)` or `.Range("A" & Row)`.

Comment: What's the error?  What line does it happen on?

Comment: I have edited my post. I meant to say "specific 'name' column", not cell. I am trying to go through the entire NAME column, not just look a the cell. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Agree with above reference the 'name' column as the actual column e.g.if the names are in column A `Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)`...

Comment: NAME column, is that a column being defined as a named range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have alluded to in the above comments, your statement

```
LR = Range("NAME" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

and also,

```
Len(Range("NAME" & i).Value)
```

just don't make any sense to VBA in your given programs, as they are the equivalent to saying.

```
Range(Name81).Value '81 is a random number
```

And unless you have a Defined Name in your workbook called Name81 (or any other number) that code will produce a Run-Time Error.

I think this gets you want you want:

```
Sub Macro2()

' Macro to delete rows if there are less than 4 in the NAME column

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, lngCol as Long

    lngCol = Rows(1).Find("NAME",lookat:=xlWhole).Column 'assumes there will always be a column with "NAME" in row 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LR To 1 Step -1

        If Len(Cells(i, lngCol).Value) < 4 Then Rows(i).Delete

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a run-time error '1004' "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.
It is occurring on this line: `LR = Cells(Rows.Count, Range(myRange).Column).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Do you have a Defined Name as **NAME** on your worksheet / in your workbook? If not, change the `myRange = "NAME"` to whatever `myRange = "[WHATEVER NAME YOU NEED]"`. If you just need a specific column, you can just to, for example, `myRange = "C1"` for column C, but if it is the case that you want to refer to specific columns, I would re-write the code a bit differently.

Comment: I am seeking to delete the rows with less than four characters that are found in only the "NAME" column. (NAME is the column Header) It is only one worksheet. How should I re-write the code when working with this specific column? ps. thanks for all your help lately.

Comment: See that is what is confusing -> you haven't been clear on what the "NAME" column is? But now, with some intution, I think it's the column with the header "NAME" (in row 1 of the column), right?

Comment: Correct. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: edited my post. Please copy all the code over, as there were changes in several spots. Also, supposes only 1 column with the word "NAME" in row 1. If you have more, or none, you get results you don't like!

Comment: There is only one "NAME" column, so this is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Your effort to answer the OP really desserves a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

For the below answer. How can the code be edited so that the row deletion only applies to a certain row and below? IE. if this should run starting row 4 down.

Sub Macro2()

' Macro to delete rows if there are less than 4 in the NAME column

```
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, lngCol as Long

lngCol = Rows(1).Find("NAME",lookat:=xlWhole).Column 'assumes there will always be a column with "NAME" in row 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LR To 1 Step -1

    If Len(Cells(i, lngCol).Value) < 4 Then Rows(i).Delete

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29794578)